# I am trying to run rails server and a, coming up this this error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a rails app with a course called one month rails. Everything was working just fine until I came across this error.

> [!] There was an error parsing Gemfile: syntax error, unexpected <<, expecting end-of-input - <<<<<<< HEAD
>   ^. Bundler cannot continue.

[image]

Comment: You know you can copy/paste code from your console instead of posting an image ?

Comment: Post some context, like what you we're trying to do, then people wont be flying blind.

Comment: OK Im new to this but very eager to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Just put a carriage return after `gem 'jquery-rails'`

Comment: Thank you I will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

The error is showing that the bundle tried to read the gemfile line by line and picks up the specified gems and install it in our system. But it faces a syntax error when we provided wrong set of arguments to gem specification.

We need to hit end line and it will work fine.

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
```

I hope it will fix your problem.

Comment: OK I will give it a try. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi I had some help solving the error, I was told that the application was broken somewhere because he tried reinstalling the gem files one by one and that didn't work. The way he fixed it he cloned the repository created a new file and reinstalled gems and that got it working again.